# Why do people keep saying the phrase "I need moral support", even though it makes no sense?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, grammar-myths

You've heard on television people say, "I need some moral support."  This is 100% the wrong phrase, grammatically incorrect, and makes no sense.  So why do people keep using it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a rant

Comment: I voted to close because it doesn't explain what the problem is.

Comment: It's not a rant; it's the truth.

Comment: The problem is clear: "I need moral support" is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say it makes no sense? It makes perfect sense. It means, I need encouragement.

Yes, "moral" here does not mean the same thing as "moral" in the sense of "right conduct". The person is not asking you to support his morality. But lots of words have more than one meaning. In this case, see this page, https://www.thefreedictionary.com/moral, definition #5, "Having psychological rather than physical or tangible effects."

We talk about an army "winning a moral victory". Not meaning that their ethics have proven superior, but that the victory inspired the army or the citizens rather than necessarily conquering a militarily significant objective.

There is the example you give, "moral support", meaning emotional or psychological support, as opposed to money or some other material aid.

Those are the two most common uses, I think.

Comment: "I need moral support" does not mean "I need encouragement".  That is precisely my point.  Definition # 5 is simply a result of sloppy English and poor usage.  It does not mean it's correct.  Anyone who says, "I need moral support" when they need encouragement is a fool.

Comment: @MonroeMann Hmm, that is exactly what it means. What are you claiming that it means? There's an interesting difference between language and, say, science. If everyone in the world agreed that the world was flat, they would all be wrong. The world would still be round. But if everyone in the world agrees that a word has a certain meaning, than that's what it means. it is meaningless to say that EVERYONE is wrong about the definition of a word. If you think the origin of a certain meaning is the result of sloppy thinking or some such, okay. But that doesn't negate the meaning.

Answer (score -5):

Short Answer: because people often aren't that smart.

Long Answer: Clearly, 95% of the population do not know the difference between the words moral and morale.

Most people think the phrase for getting supportive encouragement is 'moral support'. That is patently incorrect.

You're not asking for help making ethical decisions. If so, then "I need moral support" would make sense.  But you're not!

You are seeking help with your mood, i.e. (ta da) your morale.

Therefore, the correct phrase is 'I need some morale support', with a completely different prononciation: (moral, versus morale).

Despite this obvious distinction, most people stupidly continue to write and say, 'moral support'. Logically, when you think about it, you realize how stupid that sounds!

So I implore you: please don't speak poor English.  Just because 'moral support' is commonly used doesn't make it right.  For example, "He ain't here" is commonly heard in casual conversation, but that doesn't mean it's correct English.

Please always say, "I need some morale support", i.e. I need some MORE AL support.  Not MORUHL support.

Thank you!  Have a nice day.

Comment: Probably need to check more definitions of "moral". But more importantly, here's William Hazlitt: "I conceive that words are like money, not the worse for being common, but that it is the stamp of custom alone that gives them circulation or value."

Comment: You better write and tell [America's preeminent dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moral) that they're wrong (*adjective* 3).

Comment: Yes, they are all wrong.  Look up the words 'moral' and 'morale'.  It's obvious to anyone who actually understands English.

Comment: "I don't like this definition of a word" is a pretty pointless argument. Suppose I said that I think the word "dog" should mean "a creature with wings that flies". I could yell and scream that that's what it ought to mean. But no dictionary is going to change it because I said so, and few if any English speakers are going to change their understanding of the word because I said so. The fact that "moral" resembles "morale" is interesting and maybe that has something to do with the etymology of the phrase. I haven't bothered to look it up, because it doesn't matter. ...

Comment: ... Reminds me of a story I saw in the news about an accountant who lost his job because he used the word "niggardly" to describe a proposed budget. He was attacked for using a word that RESEMBLES a deprecating term for black people. But there's no connection, it's just coincidence. And irrelevant.